# Prevent movement to the nearest possible location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation, path-finding

[image]

As you can see in the image above when I click on the white path the object move perfectly towards the clicked position. When I click on the blue ground the object doesn't move there but it finds the nearest possible location on the white path, which is the behavior that I don't want.

I want the object to not move if the click is outside of the white path.

**Inspector:**

White Path: Navigation Static - Walkable

Blue Ground: Nothing.

**Object Script:**

```
void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
            {
                navAgent.destination = hit.point;
                navAgent.Resume();
            }
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the object to not move if the click is outside of the white
>   path.

You can do this by checking which object is clicked. You can check it by name with `hit.collider.name` or you can use tag  with `hit.collider.CompareTag` to see which object is clicked. I suggest you use tag.

Create a tag called "*whitepath*" then set your *whitepath* GameObject to this tag. You can then compare the tag name after the raycast. [This](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/tags) is Unity's  on how to create tags.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
        {
            //Check for white path
            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("whitepath"))
            {
                navAgent.destination = hit.point;
                navAgent.Resume();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.